# How to use existing SQLite database in android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am a beginner in android & eclips IDE but well in java & Netbeans IDE. I have a SQLite database which name is 'data.db' . The table name is 'words' and the columns are :

1. id
2. english
3. hindi

This database is created for a dictionary project and I want to search a specific word from 'english' column and want to show the output in a textview from the column named 'hindi' from the same row.

Suppose I want to search the word 'book' from the 'english' column and the meaning will  show in the textview in Hindi like 'किताब' .

This process is so easy in java but I didn't get any solution from the web for this because most tutorial of android SQLite database doesn't fulfill my solution.

Comment: Where you are facing difficulty?? Post some sample code what you have tried??

Comment: Hmmm... what about: `"SELECT * FROM Words WHERE English = 'book'"`? Just replace `English` with `Hindi` and `book` with `किताब` to get the reverse translation.